# Why Was The Runtime Introduced?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, compile-time, low-level

With super low level languages like Assembly there's no runtime but with anything else that's actually being used frequently like Rust, C, C++, C#, Java, Kotlin, Swift, etc there's a runtime that goes with the language. Why isn't everything done at compile time with these languages? Is it just because it'd be harder to do than using a runtime or is there some actual benefit to having a runtime?

Comment: Define 'runtime'. There is a runtime *system* associated with all languages above assembler, because all languages need a library to do I/O with, apart from anything else the language may offer in the way of APIs. Some languages have interpreted implementations where the runtime system includes an interpreter. Which is your question about?

Comment: C *does* do everything at compile time, except for actually running the program and calling the library functions, which some C implementation call the "C Runtime Library".  Are you getting mixed up between JIT VMs vs. dynamic linking to ahead-of-time compiled libraries of machine code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no there isn't a 'runtime' with C or C++ as they are fully compiled languages.
Other languages are *interpreted* - essentially the runtime as you call it is like super microcode in the processor that interprets statements in Java, PHP, BASIC, or what have you, and translates them to machine code at run time.

As to why this is done - well, to make code development faster I suppose. I am not sure that is as much a factor today as it used to be back in the days of a 4MHz z80!!!

I hope other people will add comments as this is actually an interesting question

Comment: There is a C runtime library, and a C++ runtime library, and a Fortran runtime library, and a very large Cobol runtime system, ...

Comment: It is not clear (to me) that the runtime *library* is what the original question was about.

Answer (score 1):

A programming language is a *specification*, so a written document. For C11, read the [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) standard. For Scheme, read [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/).

A programming language may have several implementations. For C on Linux, see [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [TinyCC](https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) etc.... It has several C runtime libraries ([GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/), etc).

Not all implementations have a runtime library, because some language implementations are pure interpreters. For example [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) (actually having a [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) for Scheme).

Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) for more.

Study the source code of several implementations, e.g. [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) for [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp). Or [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) or [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/) or [Chicken/Scheme](http://call-cc.org/) for Scheme.

Be aware of [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) programs.

Answer (score 1):

The *runtime library* means: the code that the compiler adds to your program.
Typically, it adapts between how the operating system works, and how the language would like the operating system to work.

People writing C would like to write `int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);` to open a file. They would not like to write `int fd; asm volatile("int 0x80" : "=a" (&fd) : "a" (1), "b" ("/dev/null"), "c" (2));`. So the runtime includes a function called `open` which has this assembly code inside it.

It would be possible for the compiler to convert the function call `open` into an `int 0x80` instruction directly - in which case it *wouldn't* be a runtime - but compiler writers would prefer to define it as a normal function which doesn't generate special instructions when you call it.

Comment: Yes, but unlike Java, the C runtime library is fully ahead-of-time compiled to machine code.  I think the OP is confused by using the same word ("runtime") in describing C libraries vs. describing VM environments like .NET and Java.  I think it would be good to explicitly point out this fact.  Also, another good example would be that `open()` is only portable to POSIX systems; C stdio `fopen()` has to be implemented *on top of* whatever low-level system calls the OS provides.

Comment: @PeterCordes The C standard library still counts as "a runtime". It's just much smaller than the Java one.

Comment: The question asks "Why isn't everything done at compile time with these languages?" - it *is* all done at compile time in C and C++.  I did already comment on the question to maybe clear up that confusion, but I was hoping if someone was going to answer, they would combine that point with some detail about what a C library does.  Although IDK if it's worth more effort at this point.  I'm not planning to answer it myself.